# reference for portfolio / margin calculations in backtesting tool

Tags: backtesting, finance-mathematics

I have been tasked with writing a backtesting tool from scratch. I understand a lot of trading operations, but I am primarily a researcher. I need to support futures and equities trading.

I need to make sure that the backtest reflects reality relatively accurately. For example trading stocks on margin, I need to know the conventions and regulatory rules that apply, and calculate buying power, pnl, margin, etc, depending on the asset class. E.g. futures margin and pnl works differently than equities.

Can anyone recommend a resource or resources that can help me fill in the gaps in my knowledge? Like a handbook of trading calculations or suchlike?